# Assign a title in html by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have an html file that I am naming my page in this line:

```
<a id="myTitle" class="brand" style=" margin-left: 110px">Title</a>
```

I would like to change the title, based on what page I am in. Right now, I change the URL to signify what page I'm on:

```
switch(page) {
        case "local":
            url += location.hostname;
            switch(datasource) {
            default:
                url += ":9001";
            }
            return url;
        case "second":
            url += "first-";
            break;
        case "third":
            url += "second-";
            break;
        }
```

The URL part works correctly, adding the local data, the "first" name, and the "second" name in my URL. I would like to attach these names on my page as it changes. so if I'm on the "first" I want the title on the page to display:

first title

if I'm on the "second" url, I want the title on the page to display:

second title

I tried adding

```
$("#myTitle").append("local");
```

but all that does is give me

titlelocallocallocallocallocal....

Is there a way to do this using jquery? javascript? I prefer jquery. Thanks guys!

Comment: The title of the page ? Just do `document.title = 'my title';`

Comment: @FabSa, thank you for your response, but when I add that, my page does nothing

Comment: @JohnConde I have added more to my question. Please remove it from hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
document.title = "Your title string";
```

So in your case, after the switch statement, you'd do:

```
document.title = url;
```

However, it seems you got your prefixes wrong and they work as postfixes.

If you want to change just the anchor text with jQuery, do this:

```
$('a.brand').text(url); // url being your string, of course
```